# Accessibility : Make UILabel with Attributed text as accessibility container

Tags: ios, uilabel, accessibility, nsattributedstring, voiceover

I have a custom view. I capture the screenshot of view and use image in NSTextAttachment as :

```
UIImage *image = view.image;
    NSTextAttachment *attachment = [NSTextAttachment new];
    attachment.image = image;
```

I then create a mutable Attributed string with this attachment as:

```
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
```

This code is looped for all views and one final attributed string is created by appending all attrStr's as:

```
[mutableString beginEditing];
    [mutableString appendAttributedString:attrStr];
    [mutableString endEditing];
```

This is then set to UILabel attributed text.

Problem : I want voice over to iterate through individual images in attributed text. So that each image is in focus by voice over.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to iterate through individual images *(like a collection view for instance)* relies on the fact to define each element as a `UIAccessibilityElement` inside a wrapper whose trait property is `adjustable`.

To understand how that should be implemented, I suggest you take a look at the `WWDC 2018 - Deliver an exceptional accessibility experience` video whose content is perfectly summarized [here](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18230.html) and whose presented example can be [downloaded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/delivering_an_exceptional_accessibility_experience).

Use of `UIAccessibilityContainer` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibilitycontainer) could be an interesting track of investigation as well.

Finally, **I don't think you could iterate your images inside the attributed text as is** but creating a kind of accessible structure perfectly understandable by VoiceOver as defined before would allow to reach your goal.